# View Controller 1 throws null pointer when button in View controller 1 segues to View Controller 2

Tags: ios, swift, null, segue

I am new to IOS dev, yet I have made a few basic apps and this one is really confusing me. In View Controller 1, I have a button which segues to View Controller 2. When I click that button, "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" occurs in the viewDidLoad() function in View Controller 1. This error occurs simply on a line which applies some styling to a button (see screen shot). This is confusing me as I don't understand why viewDidLoad() in View Controller 1 would even be called when the segue attempts to initialise View Controller 2. I have checked that View Controller 2 is attached to the correct class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please see screen shot below.

Cheers[image]

Edit: ViewController 1 loads fine and the button style is applied without issue.
Edit 2: If I remove the call to the applyButtonStyle() function, the segue works fine. Is this strange or am I missing something?

Comment: can you post your segue code?

Comment: @xTwisteDx I created the segue from the button using the ctrl drag feature in storyboards. Is that worth showing?

Comment: @xTwisteDx Please see Edit 2, confusing behaviour...

Comment: Is it possible you made the second VC a subclass of the first VC? As in `class ViewController2: ViewController1 { ... }`?

Comment: @DonMag VC2 is a subclass of UIViewController, which is correct I believe

Comment: @ThunderGrad - is your first VC class actually named `ViewController` as you show in the image? If so, double-check that your second VC is not (accidentally) `class SecondViewController: ViewController` (missing the `UI`)

Comment: @DonMag VC1 is "class ViewController: UIViewController", VC2 is "class NineHoleScoreCardViewController: UIViewController"

Comment: I am very confused at to why when I put any code in viewDidLoad() of VC1, the segue crashes the app. If I remove the code in viewDidLoad() which has anything to do with the buttons, the segue works fine... Could this be a bug in Xcode?

Comment: @DonMag Issue resolved, your suggestion RE the subclass was correct, however, due to some file naming error (by me) the class was in the wrong file so I never saw the incorrect subclassing. Many thanks!